# Using PIMPL but single header + multiple cpp files

Tags: c++, pimpl-idiom

I have a header file `class.hpp` that contains my main object

```
class Class {
public:
  Class();
  ~Class();
private:
  struct Impl;
  std::unique_ptr<Impl> impl;

};
```

I then have my main implementation `class_impl.cpp`

```
#include "Class.hpp"

struct Class::Impl {
  int x;

};

Class::Class() : impl(new Impl)
{

}
```

I now want to have another `class_impl_extended.cpp` because `class_impl.cpp` is getting very long.

I tried to do this and access impl but this fails to compile with:

```
error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct Class::Impl'
```

Comment: How is `class_impl_extended` extening `Impl`? Inheritance? Polymorhpism yes/no? Composition? Please show more details.

Comment: If a file gets too long, a split is a band aid (of the cheap kind). The class likely has a bloated api, or too many responsibilities. Both can be addressed by offshoring some of the work to smaller, more focused types.

Comment: Are you providing the `struct Class::Impl` in both files?  Or in a common-but-private header file?